# Can't get XML to load contents with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, xml

I have been trying to get an XLM document to load into an html file with the use of javascript. Please note that I haven't tried to load all the information from the XML file, but only some of it (don't think this should matter).

This is my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title> Stillinger </title>
        <style>
            table, th, td {
            border: 1px solid black;
            border-collapse:collapse;
            }
            th, td {
            padding: 5px;
            }
         </style>
    </head>
<body>
    <button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">Get available jobs</button>
    <br><br>
    <table id="stillinger"> </table>
    <script>
        function loadXMLDoc() {
            var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                    myFunction(this);   
                }
            };
            xmlhttp.open("GET", "Lab06.xml", true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        }
        function myFunction(xml) {
            var i;
            var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
            var table ="<tr><th>stilling</th><th>arbeidssted</th></tr>";
            var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("job1");
            for (i = 0; i <x.length; i++) {
                table += "<tr><td>" + 
                x[i].getElementsByTagName("STILLING") [0].childNodes [0].nodeValue + "</td><td>" + 
                x[i].getElementsByTagName("ARBEIDSSTED") [0].childNodes [0].nodeValue + "</td></tr>";
            }
            document.getElementById("stillinger").innerHTML = table;
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jobber_sentrum>
    <job1>
        <stilling>Systemadministrator ved dokumentsenteret</stilling>
        <arbeidssted> 5004 Bergen </arbeidssted>
        <arbeidsgiver> Fiskeridirektoratet </arbeidsgiver>
        <dato_registrert> 10.08.2016 </dato_registrert>
        <dato_søknadsfrist> 29.09.2016 </dato_søknadsfrist>
    </job>
    <job2>
        <stilling>Dataforvalter/analytiker</stilling>
        <arbeidssted> 5015 Bergen </arbeidssted>
        <arbeidsgiver> Folkehelseinstituttet </arbeidsgiver>
        <dato_registrert> 07.08.2016 </dato_registrert>
        <dato_søknadsfrist> 30.09.2016</dato_søknadsfrist>
    </job>
    <job3>
        <stilling> Stipendiat i rettvitskap</stilling>
        <arbeidssted> 5045 Bergen </arbeidssted>
        <arbeidsgiver> Norges Handelshøyskole </arbeidsgiver>
        <dato_registrert> 15.09.2016 </dato_registrert>
        <dato_søknadsfrist> 13.10.2016 </dato_søknadsfrist>
    </job>
    <job>
        <stilling> Soussjef/assisterende kjøkkensjef</stilling>
        <arbeidssted> Cafe Opera</arbeidssted>
        <arbeidsgiver> Cafe Opera AS </arbeidsgiver>
        <dato_registrert> 12.09.2016 </dato_registrert>
        <dato_søknadsfrist> 21.10.2016 </dato_søknadsfrist>
    </job>
</jobber_sentrum>
```

Does anybody see what the mistake is?

Comment: Well, what does the browser console say?

Comment: stillinger.html:29 XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/Joachim/Documents/Dropbox/INFO100/Lab06/Lab06.xml. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.loadXMLDoc @ stillinger.html:29

Comment: So there is your problem..... Has nothing to do with the code, has to do you can not use the XMLHttpRequest on the file protocol. You should be running a local server so you do not run into these issues. A really bad idea is to load your browser with flags so it does allow file access.

Comment: Okay, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

```
var xml = "<rss version='2.0'><channel><title>RSSTitle</title</channel></rss>",   
xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml ),   
$xml = $( xmlDoc ),   
$title = $xml.find( "title" );
console.log($title.text()); // it will print RSSTitle
```

Use xml parser and find specific tag from xml response and use it,
   Hope this may help you..